# PIL image and matplotlib plot gets saturated black and white for png image

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, python-imaging-library

I have the following mammogram image and I am trying to read this using PIL image and then plot it using matplotlib:

[image]

The code I am using is:

```
%matplotlib inline
from PIL import Image
from matplotlib.pyplot import imshow
from scipy.misc import imread
path = './sample.png'
image = Image.open(path).convert('RGB')
imshow(image)
```

But I am getting this image:

[image]

Why it's not showing the correct image?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to convert image after loading to numpy array to process with matplotlib. To show image in grey scale use `grey` colormap over-vise image will be shown in color mode.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.pyplot import imshow
from scipy.misc import imread
path = './1.png'
image = Image.open(path)
plt.imshow(np.asarray(image), cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

[image]